# Update Oozie Coordinator definition

Tags: java, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have a running coordinator which was scheduled by Oozie java client.
Now I need to update its definition fields like frequency, start, end .
I tried Oozie java client's updateCoor() function but it's throwing an exception like we could not update the coordinator definition but only its properties.
Is someone has found any solution to it .please suggest?
One solution is to kill the old coordinator and create a new with new configurations but we need to keep history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update frequency, start time and end time of a oozie coordinator . All the other properties can be updated with -update option .